# Get XML response when calling webservice method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asmx

Is it possible to get XML response parallel with calling webservice method;

For example:

```
var ws = new WebReference.WService();
String result = ws.HelloWorld();
```

I need to get XML response from webservice for `HelloWorld()` function like

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

and parallel string result in variable `result = "Hello World"`

Comment: You need to add more detail to improve this question, what is the `result`? is it not XML? As it stands this question does not show research effort, is unclear and not useful.

Comment: Probably not.  The service will not be running until the webervice completes so the GetResult method will not work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid calling the same method twice, you'll need to move to a WCF approach, implementing an `IEndpointBehavior` behavior to read the raw communication with your webservice endpoint.

An example for such behavior can be found at [Generic WCF Host](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24349/Generic-WCF-Host).

Answer (score 0):

This is answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13779722/1179895. But it is necessary to add service reference to project as a service, NOT **web**service.